To find how many times greater a number a is than b
An example, 6 and 2, since my point of view 6 contents 2, 3 times. But for me, 6 would be 2 time grater than 2, because 6 = 2(first 2) + 2(second 2) + 2(third 2) then 6 = (1st 2 iqual to 2) + (2nd 2 one time grater than 2) + (3rd 2 two time grater than 2). Why since of school I heard something like this: 50/10 = 5, which means that 50 is 5 times greater than 10 ?

6 is three times greater than 2. If you want to say 6 is two times greater, you would need a different phrasing, maybe "2 and two times again greater", anything I can think of is going to be clunky. This is not really a maths question, it's an English question.

Also consider that $6$ is $200%$ greater than $2$, and $200% = 2$.

Unrelated, but I hate when I hear in news report "three times less." Ugh, I really hate that.
